# What specs would a tablet need to run painting apps (mypaint, etc.) well?

Tags: hardware, ubuntu-netbook, graphics, multi-touch, tablet

I want to pick up a tablet or touch-enabled laptop to use for drawing and painting with a stylus. But I'm not sure whether one of the convertible netbooks from Asus and others would have the guts to drive the graphics apps well. (I generally use mypaint, gimp, and inkscape.) What do people think would be a minimum usable hardware configuration? By usable, I mean being able to make a quick stroke with a stylus on a reasonably large mypaint file and not have lag in its appearing on the screen. Is the issue mainly ram? Can any of the mobile (i.e., netbook) processors do the job? All of this is, again, assuming that I'm running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

The main limitting factor is your memory, screen resolution can effect the responsiveness too. I'd say a 2Ghz Core2 with a 512MB Video card and about 2GB of RAM should do well for medium sizes (3kx4k) and large complex vector images.